# how to run multiple iteration a single api in a collection in postman runner?

Tags: postman, runner

In postman runner, I can run all apis in a collection for multiple iterations. Is there a way that I can pick one api and run it multiple iterations?

Answer (score 2):

Two ways:
1. you can create another collection and add your iterative test in that collection.

---

2. you can create a folder under your collection and add your test in the folder to iterative testing.[see attached screenshots]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not really what I want but thanks for the idea. I have dozens of tests in the collection, sometimes want to run just one, and sometimes want to run several of them depends on situation. It will be ideal if postman has option to select want tests to run.

Answer (score 0):

In the later versions of postman (I'm running `Version 7.14.0`), there is an option to control the order of execution of the tests and you can also uncheck the ones you don't want to run.

[image]